# differentiate which files had merge conflicts in commit

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a `master` branch and have branched off a `feature-x` branch. The `master` branch has received several bug fixes across multiple files. The `feature-x` branch has created several files and has only touched a single file common with the `master` branch. When I got to keep the `feature-x` branch up to date with all of the bug fixes, I merge in the `master` branch. Because of the change to that one common file, I get a merge conflict in that file. I fix the conflicts in the file and at this point all the following files are staged automatically by git:

- All files that were patched in `master`
- All new files created in `feature-x`

I then have to stage my updated common file and commit to finish/resolve the merge.

If I look at the merge commit on GitHub/BitBucket, it looks like tons of files were touched and there's no way to determine which ones had and didn't have merge conflicts.

Is this just the nature of the beast? Or is there a better way to do this to be able to identify in the commit which files were merged automatically and which ones had to have manual help?

In my project, I seem to get bit by merging branches sometimes and can't pinpoint in the merge commits where things went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to rebase your feature branch on top of Master and then merge the changes.  This would pull in all of the changes/bug fixes on master into your branch and then replay all of the commits on top of them.  You would still get the merge conflict in the one file that both had changed so you would just need to resolve that conflict and then you can push.

If you've already pushed your branch to a remote, you would need to force push.

Comment: thanks Keif, i just read up on `git pull --rebase` and i think that's what I want.